# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I have seen several similar posts on this topic, but none of them apply to my case. I have gathered based on those posts that this is likely caused by one of my Firebase dependencies, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem. Cleaning, invalidating, et al have already been done, and all of my dependencies have been updated to their latest versions. Here are my gradle files:

Project:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.andrewedgar.theo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to downgrade firebase core library to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

If it will not help, try to downgrade some another firebase libraries. In my case it was also:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.2'
```

Comment: This allowed me to keep working, though hopefully a solution is found that doesn't require people to use old versions. Thank you.

Comment: yes, `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'` causes it, `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'` works fine

Comment: @user924 I have 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4' in my app, but the issue exists.