# Can't use Firebase ads: No static method zzc(Landroid/os/Bundle;

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, admob

I'm trying to add the Firebase ads library to my project (which is already live), the build works but when i try to run it crashes with this error:

> 11-16 10:33:13.535 540-540/com.dap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                        Process: com.dap, PID: 540 **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzc(Landroid/os/Bundle;)Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzak; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzak; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzak' appears in /data/app/com.dap-AZ0LDvxgjJKn7K-a-EQ0QQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)**
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnectorImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source:20)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.zzb.create(Unknown Source:6)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:43)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:54)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:26)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:34)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:82)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:761)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:359)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:324)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:310)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:53)
>                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
>                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
>                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:47)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7107)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6594)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6498)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1963)
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

All my Firebase / Google libraries are up to date [firebase latest version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions):

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

// Facebook libraries
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0'

// Firebase/Google libraries
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'

// Support libraries (don't use the global support library)
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'

// Other libraries
implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
implementation 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.github.guilhe:seekbar-ranged-view:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As long as my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I've tried to downgrade some libraries like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217012/error-program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-internal-measurement) advice too. No success. 
I've tried to downgrade gms:play-services-location, but no success.
Instead of adding the ads library from Firebase i've tried the one from Google but i get this error: 
`"Error: Program type already present:         com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz"`

I've also tried to Clean and Rebuilt project, uninstall app on my phone, Invalidate Cache and Restart. But i keep getting the same error.

I'll keep digging but for now i can't find a way to make these Firebase libs to work together.

Finally if it can help anyone, here my gradlew app:dependencies:

```
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |                   +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |                   \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.32.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.32.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.32.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.32.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.32.0
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.32.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.32.0
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.32.0 (*)
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.4
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.5
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.10
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.5
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.6.5
|         +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.4 (*)
|         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.5
+--- com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4 -> 16.0.5
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3] -> 16.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3] -> 16.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 -> 17.0.4
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1
|    |    |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
|    |    |    |              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |              |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 -> 17.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3] -> 16.2.3 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.2
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.0.2 -> 16.0.3 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4 -> 16.0.5 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 -> 16.2.3 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[17.0.4] -> 17.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:16.0.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
+--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0 -> 3.8.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1 -> 16.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.3
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3] -> 16.2.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:16.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-abt:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 -> 16.2.3 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4 -> 16.0.5 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 -> 16.2.3 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 -> 17.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.5
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.5
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:[16.1.3] -> 16.1.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 -> 17.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[17.1.1] -> 17.1.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[17.1.1] -> 17.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[17.1.1] -> 17.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.0.3
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:[17.1.1] -> 17.1.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[17.1.1] -> 17.1.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:2.0.0-alpha2
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3
+--- com.android.support:percent:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
+--- com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:1.1.2
+--- com.github.guilhe:seekbar-ranged-view:1.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
\--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 -> 1.0.3

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)
```

Sorry for all the codes blocks, but i thought it would be more easier to understand.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i found a solution to my problem, but it's not really the best way in my opinion.

I had to downgrade several firebase lib until it works as you can see on my graddle.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
```

Apparently some libs depend on each other. For now i won't update them to their latest version...
It would be really appreciated if i could have more information about this.

Comment: (1) Only ever include libraries that *you* need, and let others be added automatically. E.g. firebase-core will add firebase-analytics at the version it depends on. (2) Use most recent versions, or if you have to use older ones make sure they were out at the same time (see release dates at https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.google.firebase) (3) Do https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning#strict_version_matching and see if it give you any hints.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. firebase-core and firebase-ads work in this version combination. Does anyone know the freshest one compatibility for these 2 libs?

Comment: Latest version 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0' and    'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0' seems to work fine. All my libs are up to date, didn't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

please replace `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1` with `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **firebase-core** and **firebase-ads** are **up to date** by specifying the last version.

At the time of writing my answer they are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'** to **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'**

Comment: Hi buddy, there's an issue with `FirebaseCore` gradle dependency version `16.0.5` is not available. And `+` will be searching for it which is not available yet. I think you are lucky if it helped you.

Comment: When you don't specify a version, you will always have the latest version. If you only have one firebase library it can works, but as you can see my app have plenty of them and they can be related. It can lead to bugs.
Plus, sometimes a new version can have major changes. I think it is best to be aware of every changes by checking the patch notes :)

Answer (score 0):

well i have spent 2 days on the exact same pbs. So first, i changed 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4' -> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5' but, when running it, it could not find the exact version 16.0.5. So what ends up working weirdly for me, is to change 
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4' -> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'

Here is my app level build.gradle dependencies, in case it might be helpful: 
dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


configurations.androidTestImplementation.dependencies.each { androidTestImplementationDependency ->
    androidTestImplementationDependency.exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

implementation ("com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0") {
    force = true //<-- force dependency resolution to 28.0.0 in my case
}
implementation project(':slyce-messaging')
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
implementation 'net.rimoto:intlphoneinput:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.marlonlom:timeago:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Below is the error message, i got same thing : 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzc(Landroid/os/Bundle;)Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzak; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzak; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzak' appears in ...)
        at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnectorImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.zzb.create(Unknown Source)

Comment: Be careful, when a new version of Firebase core will be live you're app will use this one. It can introduce another bugs that you won't be enable to manage on production before uploading a new version.

It seems there are conflict between Firebase versions of Core, Ads and probably others... :/

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same with these versions of firebase in my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

to solve the issue it was enough to update firebase to the most recent version at the time of writing:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
```

and clean/rebuild the project.